# Interparticular space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry

We say that the **inter-particular space** in  solids is small,in liquid is intermediate and in gas it is huge.So,how small is that space.there must be parameters for the amount of **space**.Like when the space becomes x then it is a solid; not a liquid or a gas.Then when the **space** becomes y it is a liquid and so on.
Sorry for the length of the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phases aren't really about the properties they are about the boundaries.

A good analogy is fences. There might be some fences along property lines, but there could be sections of property lines without a fence. For instance, in many locations the sidewalk is part of your property, but a part where easements allow the public to travel. So the sidewalk part of your property and the sidewalk part of your neighbor's property might not have a fence.

Now imagine that the fence is small, that it's really just a marker. Then you might not have a fence along the sidewalk. So to go from your property to your neighbor's property you could do straight there by stepping over the fence, or you could walk to the sidewalk, walk in the sidewalk to your neighbor's and then step into your neighbor's property. This time, without crossing a fence.

The same thing happens with water. Water only has solid, liquid, and gas phases above the triple point temperature. If you had some water vapor (steam, water gas) at one atmosphere and 400 K and you increased the pressure there would be this phase boundary at pressure $P_1$ where it converts to liquid water and then you can keep increasing the pressure up to $P_2=P_1+0.001atm$. That boundary is like the fence. When you cross it, you cross a phase boundary. The reason the liquid and gas are so very different for slightly different pressures is because a lot happens on the boundary.

But instead you can increase the temperature a huge amount, to be bigger than the critical temperature $T_{cr}$ and then increase the pressure to be a bit bigger than the critical pressure $P_{cr}$ then decrease the temperature to be a bit below the critical temperature $T_{cr}$ and then decrease the temperature and pressure down to 400K and $P_2$ and now you have the exact same water as you have when you crossed the phase boundary when you merely increased the pressure. But this time you didn't cross any phase boundaries.

So the first route you reached a transition pressure during which the density got smaller while the temperature and pressure stayed the same. At this transition the average spacing between the molecules got smaller and smaller and smaller.

But that second route never crossed a phase boundary. So the density changed smoothly and there never was a density along that second path where it changed from one phase to another. The gas and the liquid are both fluids.

In that second route, you could change the density a little bit by increasing the temperature a little bit and keep doing that. And then you could change the density a little bit by increasing the pressure a little bit and keep doing that. And then you could change the density a little bit by decreasing the temperature a little bit and keep doing that. And finally you could change the density a little bit by decreasing the pressure and temperature a little bit, and keep doing that. It was always changing the density a little bit by changing the temperature and/or pressure a little bit.

But when when you took the first route you changed the density by increasing the pressure and it was fine until you reached that transition pressure $P_1$ and that's where a ohase transition happened. In the ohase transition you had all steam but pockets of liquid water form that are more incompressible that the steam. So what happens is that as more and more steam converts to water the pressure and temperature stay the same as the density drops and drops and drops.

So there are a whole range of densities (and corresponding average distance between molecules) corresponding to a mixture of steam and liquid water. But there isn't some cutoff density. If you increased the density by the other route, there would be no ohase boundary, the density would always chnage a little but for every little change in temperature and/or pressure.

So it's like one property with a fence. You can walk around the fence and there is no boundary where things change a lot, or you can go over the fence. If you go over the fence, you will want names for the two sides so you can discuss where you are and what percentage of the substance is on which side of the fence. But the regions on both sides are technically connected.

So there isn't a magic density (and hence no magic intermolecular distance). The same density might be a gas or a liquid or a solid depending on the temperature. And phase isn't about density either. Its about boundaries, and the boundaries aren't necessarily between regions that aren't connected.